# VRP: Changing a dynamic bridge priority to a static priority value

Tags: spanning-tree, vrp

On a switch running Huawei VRP: What is the safest way to deconfigure a dynamic priority value on a root bridge and then configure a static priority value?

*What's the problem?*

I can do this:

```
[Switch]stp instance 0 priority 20480
[Switch]stp instance 0 root primary
```

But I can't do this:

```
[Switch]stp instance 0 root primary
[Switch]stp instance 0 priority 20480
```

So I have to do this:

```
[Switch]undo stp instance 0 root
[Switch]stp instance 0 priority 20480
```

In the meantime, the bridge has a priority value of 32768.

I can't assign a priority value because the command is not accepted: *Error: Failed to modify priority because the switch is configured as a primary root or secondary root.*

Currently, I have three options. None of them are satisfying. 1) Disconnect the bridge from the network and configure it from a terminal. 2) Decrease the priority value on every other bridge below the default value of 32768. 3) Deconfigure and reconfigure as fast as possible and hope for the best.

Comment: If you are using the `primary` or `secondary` keywords to set the priority, why do you then want to change the priority right away? In effect, you are setting the priority, then setting it again. The default value is `32786`, and setting the priority to `root` sets the value below the default value, and setting the priority value to `secondary` sets it somewhere between the `root` and default values. You should not need to change the value after setting it to `root`.

Comment: I don't want to change it right away. It's an example of what can be done and what can't be done in VRP. It's supposed to show that those command can't be entered in any sequence.

Comment: "_It's supposed to show that those command can't be entered in any sequence._" OK, many network devices have commands which cannot be entered in just any sequence. Before entering a new command, it is sometimes required that you remove a previous command. There is nothing unusual about that. For instance, on a Cisco switch, you will need to remove the `switchport` command with `no switchport` before you can enter the `ip address <address> <mask>` command.

Comment: Changing a configuration on a network device without first understanding the current configuration can cause big problems. The behavior you describe prevents you from making a foolish mistake and possibly changing the root of the LAN by accident. You seem to get a proper message, which will lead you to the correct solution: either leave it alone, or remove the root status first.

Comment: IOS is a good example because it allows what I'm forbidded to do on VRP. I doubt that VRP has a flaw. It must be my fault, my lack of understanding.

Comment: IOS actually does something different by setting the priority to `root`. IOS doesn't guarantee that the switch will be the root switch when you use the `root` keyword.

Comment: IOS uses a bridge priority value that is lower than the default, regardless of `root primary` or `root secondary`. On VRP, `root primary` causes the bridge to use 0 and `root secondary` causes the bridge to use 4096. In contrast to IOS, there is no relation to other bridges in the topology. This makes the situation even worse if somebody wants to change from `root primary` to `priority`.

Comment: "_This makes the situation even worse if somebody wants to change from root primary to priority._" Exactly. IOS will let you hang yourself, whereas VRP tries to protect you. You want VRP to be something it is not, and do something it doesn't do. The workaround is to never use the `root` keyword, but simply set the root to a specific value, then you can change it later without your problem of needing to reset it  to the default value. I still don't see why you would want change the value on a root switch, anyway.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

When you specify the bridge as a root bridge, you are, in fact, setting the priority -- to a value lower than any other bridge.

You can't have it both ways:  Either you make the bridge the root and let the switch figure out the best priority value,

OR,

if you want to set a particular priority value, then you can't say it's the root.  It may end up being the root if you set the priority low enough, but that's not guaranteed.

Comment: I don't want to have it both ways. I want to change the current setting. VRP doesn't allow to overwrite the `stp instance 0 root primary` command, although it allows to overwrite the `stp instance 0 priority 20480` command with `stp instance 0 root primary`.

Comment: Then the last example you posted is correct.  Undo the root command, then set the priority.

Comment: I know that the last example is correct. However, it has a pitfall: For at least a second, the default priority value is in force. I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: Hmmm.  I don't know a way around that.  I suppose you could raise the priority value of the other switches so no TCNs are sent.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve, or is this just a lab exercise?

Comment: I need a workaround for two reasons: 1) The same situation would never occur on IOS because the dynamic priority value could be overwritten. 2) At the moment, I can afford to disconnect the switch and change its settings because there is redundancy. But it may happen that either I or somebody else runs into the same problem and won't be so lucky. I want to be prepared. 3) I doubt that VRP has a flaw. It must be my fault, my lack of understanding.